# Using regex in WHERE in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I currently have the the following query:

```
select regexp_matches(name, 'foo') from table;
```

How can I rewrite this so that the regex is in the where like the following (not working):

```
select * from table where regexp_matches(name, 'foo');
```

Current error message is:
ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text[]
SQL state: 42804
Character: 29

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Write instead:

```
select * from table where name ~ 'foo'
```

The '~' operator produces a boolean result for whether the regex matches or not rather than extracting the matching subgroups.

Comment: Is there an alternative to ~ operator? I'm using a javascript library that parses a query and unfortunately, it doesn't recognize ~ and any variants thereof.

Comment: @Martin You could try using SIMILAR TO which has stripped down regular expression support  

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name SIMILAR TO 'foo'`  

See the [documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) for more details

Comment: @JoshFrankel :  I read somewhere (I think on stackoverflow) that SIMILAR TO has worse performance.

Comment: @Nina Possibly, I'm not sure offhand. SIMILAR TO uses regex features but doesn't completely implement them which maybe makes it a special case and therefore less performant. I prefer the `~` regex operator as there aren't any surprises concerning what is implemented and what isn't as there are with SIMILAR TO

Comment: @JoshFrankel: what about this case ?

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221146/pl-pgsql-function-to-test-if-a-word-is-contained-within-a-phrase?noredirect=1#comment429053_221146

this is a question i have posted lately

Comment: What if `foo` is `J(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])`? Won't you get multiple records WHERE-clause violation?