# SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL + PG regex

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, sqlalchemy

SA has support for regexes but those seem to be Python regexps ([Regular expressions in SQLalchemy queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112337/regular-expressions-in-sqlalchemy-queries))

I need to use regex on matching some rows (a row contains 1 log line, so regex is a natural match) but for performance reasons I would prefer to do it using PG backend, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945477/using-regex-in-where-in-postgres):

```
select * from table where name ~ 'foo';
```

How can I combine both PG-implemented regex AND SQLAlchemy object selection in one query?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=filter#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method of the Query object allows for you to use raw SQL for the filter. So, you could do...

```
Table.query.filter("name ~ 'foo'")
```

Note that if you want to provide this as an argument, you can use [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) and [`params()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.params)...

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

Table.query.filter(text('name ~ :reg')).params(reg='foo')
```

Because we define the "reg" bind parameter in the filter using `text()`, we need to make sure we define the value, which we can do using `params()`.

Comment: Thank you!! This thing with bind parameters is also very useful (protection against sql injection and the like).

Answer (score 30):

Note that you can also use the infix operator support:

```
session.query(Table).filter(Table.name.op("~")('foo'))
```