# Filter REGEX in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables `users` and `users_address` and I'm trying to get all users with an incomplete name or address.

Everything works well except the filter related to postal routing, where I search a pattern of :

**(some digits)+(a space)+(some letters or spaces)**

Here is my code:

```
    ua = aliased(UserAddress)

    # Main query, incomplete users or addresses
    query1 = DBSession.query(
        User.id,
        User.member_id,
        User.lastname,
        User.firstname,
        ua.supplemental_address_1,
        ua.supplemental_address_2,
        ua.supplemental_address_3,
        ua.street_address,
        ua.postal_routing,
        ua.country,
    ).distinct()

    query1 = query1.join(ua, User.addresses)

    query1 = query1.filter(
        sa.or_(
            User.lastname == u'',
            User.firstname == u'',
            sa.and_(
                ua.primary == True,
                sa.or_(
                    ua.country == u'',
                    sa.and_(
                        ua.supplemental_address_1 == u'',
                        ua.supplemental_address_2 == u'',
                        ua.supplemental_address_3 == u'',
                        ua.street_address == u'',
                    ),
                    ~ua.postal_routing.op('regexp')('\d*\ ?(\w\s)*'),
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

But I got this error :

`ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "regexp"
LINE 4: ...ress = '' OR NOT (user_addresses_1.postal_routing regexp '[[...`

I think a made a mistake in the way to call the regex, and I'm pretty sure my regex itself is mis formated :(

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Don't add "(Solved)" to the title. You've indicated that by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, self answer.

as I see in [Using regex in WHERE in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945477/using-regex-in-where-in-postgres),
the correct REGEX call in Postgresql is `~`
so, the correct syntax is:

`-`  `~ua.postal_routing.op('regexp')('\d*\ ?(\w\s)*'),`

`+` `~ua.postal_routing.op('~')('^\d+ \w+$'),`

By the way, I changed the pattern.

Maybe is there a better syntax, but this one is working for me.