# To find particular value in sql expression either by expression or by regular expression way

Tags: postgresql

I have the following data in the **value** field.

```
Sample data 
-------------------
cid    value
--------------------
1     'This is test message for&nbsp;*NAME_FIRST*&nbsp;<br />*NAME_LAST*<br />We should strict to rules for inspections.<br /><br />Thanks,
2     'Hello &nbsp;*NAME_FIRST*&nbsp;<br />*NAME_LAST*<br />Hope you are doing good.<br /><br />Thanks,'
```

I want to find all such data that have *NAME_FIRST* OR *NAME_LAST* pattern in value. I wrote following select query but something is wrong and I am not able to get results.

```
 SELECT * FROM template_custom_texts tct WHERE tct.cid = 1 AND tct.value = E'\\*(NAME_FIRST|NAME_LAST)\\*';
```

I used another way as well like this :

```
SELECT * FROM template_custom_texts tct WHERE tct.cid = 1 AND regexp_matches(tct.value, '(NAME_FIRST|NAME_LAST)', 'g');
```

In both query results do not arrive.

Comment: could you update your post with some sample data? i.e., where do you get `CUSTOMER_NAME_FIRST`?  Which column is it?  what would a sample `tct.value` look like?

Comment: @richyen edited question slightly. We want to find out NAME_FIRST & NAME_LAST respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using regex in WHERE in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945477/using-regex-in-where-in-postgres) Did you try Googling for ___postgresql regexp_matches in where clause___ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM template_custom_texts 
WHERE cid = 1 AND value ~ 'NAME_FIRST|NAME_LAST';
```

Bear in mind this query is case sensitive and you can replace `~` with `~*` for case insensitive matching.

Have a read of the documentation for PostgreSQL pattern matching too: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html.